# Stochasticity challenge

Tags: probability, combinatorics

If a string of characters (S) that is 325384 long, contains 458 As and 22 Bs. What is the probability that if the 458 As and 22 Bs were randomly positioned along the 325384 string of characters that there would be exactly 861 characters between at least one of the AB pairs.

Whilst I am interested in the probability of this occurring, I would also like to see how to calculate it for any given value of A,B,S or value of characters between them.

Comment: It will be tiny, but there's no way of knowing it because it depends on word lengths, successive words aren't independent, etc.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because t
here's nothing meaningfully statistical about this comparison. Why do we know that 1 word should equal 0.01 light year, as opposed to 1 parsec, 1 astronomical unit, or 1 furlong? Why choose Sirius instead of any other star? If you scour the world with a particular *motivated reasoning*, you'll find any number of coincidences that appear to be meaningful; The term for this is *apophenia.*

Comment: I don't think this out the other question is off topic. How to calculate probability of something given some other numbers is on topic. If a question includes elements of forking paths, cherry picking, and other statistical fallacies that should be explained in the answer or in the comments but it's still not off topic

Comment: I am voting to reopen, now that this is phrased as an abstract probability question, but wish to point out that the answer does *not* apply to the original question about the Quran, because it is a *post hoc* hypothesis.  Regardless, it's virtually certain there will at least 861 characters between some A and some neighboring B and it's virtually certain there will be some A and a neighboring B separated by fewer than 861 characters.